# python. If a program stops, a new instance must start

Tags: python, multithreading, process, wait, execute

Windows 7 64bit, python26

I run a minecraft server, but sometimes the program is stoped for different reasons. I would like a new instance to start when that happens.

The following code works for notepad.exe, but keeps spawning new minecraft_servers even tho the previous one didnt' stop. Why? And what should I do?

I'm new to python.

```
import Queue, thread, subprocess, time

results= Queue.Queue()
def process_waiter(popen, description, que):
    try: popen.wait()
    finally: que.put( (description, popen.returncode) )
process_count= 0

while True:
    proc1= subprocess.Popen( "C:\\Users\\Bo\\AppData\\Roaming\\.minecraf\\Minecraft_Server.exe")
    thread.start_new_thread(process_waiter,
    (proc1, "1 finished", results))
    process_count+= 1

    time.sleep(10)

    while process_count > 0:
        description, rc= results.get()
        print "job", description, "ended with rc =", rc
        process_count-= 1
```

Comment: I assume the problem has to do with the program spawning a new process.

Answer (score 3):

It is unclear why threading is involved in the process restarter.
Does this work for you:

```
while True:
    proc = subprocess.Popen("C:\\Users\\Bo\\AppData\\Roaming\\.minecraf\\Minecraft_Server.exe")
    proc.wait()
    print 'Minecraft_Server process terminated.  Restarting now'
```

Suggestions:

- start with a few lines of code that works, then add features
- use *threading* in instead of *thread*
- don't name a variable "popen" because of its similarity to the name of the function in subprocess.
- add logging or print statements so you can tell what the script is doing
- monitor the process creation with the task manager

Comment: This does not work for me. It does not wait, but spawn multiple instances. It does how ever work with for notepad.exe.